# JavaScript.JQuery toggle and fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, fadein

If you have one div with two radio buttons with no ids and each one disables content and displays new content if selected. Should be simple but its not working properly. When the radio button is changed, toggle off that content and fade in the new content and vice versa.
What is wrong with this code? Is it not this simple?

```
<div class="radios">
                <div class="change__radio">
                    Home: <input name="change" type="radio" value="1" checked="true" />
                    Projects <input name="change" type="radio" value="2" />
                </div> 



 $(":radio").change( function(e) {
            $(".radios__home").toggle().fadeIn(400);
            $(".radios__projects").toggle().fadeIn(400);});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML as part of the question....

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `.fadeIn` always makes the element visible, regardless of what you do with `.toggle`. So you need to check the value of the checked radio and use that to fade in/hide the appropriate element. Something like this (but hopefully a bit prettier):

```js
$(":radio").change(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $(".radios__home").fadeIn(400);
    $(".radios__projects").hide();
  } else {
    $(".radios__home").hide();
    $(".radios__projects").fadeIn(400);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <div class="change__radio">
    Home: <input name="change" type="radio" value="1" checked="true" /> Projects <input name="change" type="radio" value="2" />All
  </div>



  <div class="radios__home" style="display:block">Home Radio</div>
  <div class="radios__projects" style="display:none">Projects Radio</div>

</div>
```

Comment: instead of fadeout, toggle would work also im assuming?

Comment: @lucklshot yes, you can just use toggle with a duration. See my edit.

Comment: yeah but it still fades out, instead of fade out I would like instantly to toggle of/disappear and fade in when called

Comment: @lucklshot see my edit; that will fade in the new div but instantly hide the old one